# Date format in google shee

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets-api, google-workspace

[google-sheets-api] I'm currently working on google sheet (excel) but having problems due to date formats. Our original excel sheet contains the format (dd/mm/yyyy which we cannot change) and when we paste the cells in google sheet it takes it as mm/dd/yyyy by default. This makes our data incorrect. Is there any way we can change google sheet date format to dd/mm/yyyy as we can't change the date format of our original data.

Comment: with api? What language are you using to access the api?

Comment: What locale do you use: (Main menu: File>Settings)?

Comment: Pllease provide [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

Use **File > Settings > Locale** to change to a locale that matches the date format you need to use.

To set the locale programmatically, use [Spreadsheet.setSpreadsheetLocale()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#setspreadsheetlocalelocale) method or its equivalent.